# How cell sites work?

Tags: rf, transmitter, microwave, telecommunications, optical-fibre

In Mobile communication, how do cell sites communicate to each other to the point when they reach the cell site which is connected to the other mobile phone when I make a call .
What is the medium of communication (optic fibre or microwave links)?

Comment: There should be many articles available on this topic published on the web already. If you need someone to write an answer here then please narrow it down to a part that you don't understand and give a reference link to the article in question. What has your research shown?

Comment: Can you provide an article related to my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What is the medium of communication (optic fiber or microwave links)*

It can be either, or a even a copper based cable.

It depends on what is most convenient in a certain situation. On top of a mountain or a building a microwave link would probably be the most suitable (cost effective). But if that building already has fiber connections to elsewhere, that might be more cost effective.

So, there is no answer like: Every base station is connected through a microwave link as that isn't true. It depends on the circumstances.

Comment: I like this answer, although it just states the obvious (which almost always is true): It depends. Also, "Cell Site" is terribly undefined. A "cell site" can also be a DSL-attached femtocell box in the corner of a room, or a fully fledged mast carrying dozens of antennas including intelligence that directly attaches to a fibre back bone. So, really, I hope OP appreciates the "sorry, no general answer can be given" and moves it in his/her heart!